# Slide disappearing in Beamer with \beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}

Tags: beamer, overlays, quotation

I have the following slide.  `\beamerdefaultoverlayspecification{<+->}` is used in the document.

```
\begin{frame}\frametitle{The problem}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item First item
  \item Second item
    \begin{quote}
      \uncover<2>{
      ``A quote illustrating the second item that I want to reveal together with that item.''
      }
    \end{quote}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

As it says, I want to reveal the quote at the same time as the second item is revealed.  If I don't put in the `\uncover`, the quote is revealed in a separate step.  But if I do put it in, then **the quote is not displayed at all.** (Text added after the `itemize` environment is still displayed, it's only the quote the disappears.)

The problem can be solved in this inelegant way:

```
\begin{frame}\frametitle{The problem}
  \begin{itemize}
  \item First item
  \item<2> Second item
    \begin{quote}
      \uncover<2>{
      ``A quote illustrating the second item that I want to reveal together with that item.''
      }
    \end{quote}
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
```

Can anyone explain what's happening here?  Why does the quote disappear?  Why is the `<2>` necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`quote` is overlay-aware and that's why it follows the default overlay specification of `+-` (becoming visible as another element in a sequential way). You can force the `quote` on the second slide (with the second `\item`) using

```
\begin{quote}<2>
  % <your quote>
\end{quote}
```

The reason why the quote doesn't appear when you use `\uncover<2>` is because the `quote` environment itself is set to appear on `<3>`. So, it can't show anything on the 3rd slide since the contents of the `quote` is only `\uncover`ed on the 2nd.

Comment: OK, thanks, I understand now.  But that just leads to the question: is there a way so I don't have to write \begin{quote}<2>, and have instead a relative way to specify that it should appear together with the last slide?

Comment: @GrB: It would be easier to just force the occasional overlay specification when you need it? It may just be that you can't have your cake and eat it here...

Comment: Fair enough... Thanks!